# Creating a Little World Image

Tags: image-processing, projection

I was wondering how we go about creating the so-called Little World/ Small World images from standard photos. I am unable to get the projection formulas, and help on this front would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to such an image: http://www.appleiphoneschool.com/2011/06/13/tinyworld-turn-pictures-into-their-own-little-world/

Sincerely,
thegratefulguest.

Comment: like us to some examples so we get an idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to project like this you need first to reproject your image to a sphere.

Then you just need a camera placed at the north pole looking inside to the south pole (and open de FOV angle !)